# Error creating web service in a Model

Tags: tridion

I am trying to create a data model to work with my GUI extension, I have created a simple service that returns a string. I have configured the model.config and added the following entry in my web.config

```
<services>
    <service name="CMSExtensions.Model.Services.PublicationInfo" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.DeveloperBehavior">
        <endpoint name="PublicationInfo" address="" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.WebHttpBindingConfig" contract="CMSExtensions.Model.Services.PublicationInfo"/>
    </service>      
</services>
```

When I try to run this service directly in the browser I get the following error:

Parser Error Message: There is no service behavior named `'Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.DeveloperBehavior'`.

and when i try to invoke it via the JS in GUI I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'GetPublicationData' of undefined
CMSExtensions.Popups.PublicationInfo._onExecuteButtonClickedPublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:433
(anonymous function)PublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:2
EventRegister.f.executeListenerPublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:16
aPublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:16
Tridion.ObjectWithEvents.processHandlersPublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:14
Tridion.ObjectWithEvents.fireEventPublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:14
Tridion.Controls.Button.onclickPublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:428
Tridion.Controls.Button.onmouseupPublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:428
(anonymous function)PublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:2
EventRegister.f.executeListenerPublicationInfo_v6.0.0.39607.0_.aspx:16
a
```

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 (no SP1).

Here is the Service code

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using CMSExtensions.Model.Progress;
using Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54;


namespace CMSExtensions.Model.Services
{

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://CMSExtensions.Model.Services", Name = "PublicationInfo")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]

    public class PublicationInfo : WCFServiceBase
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string GetUserDescription()
        {
            return "sachin";
        }
    }
}
```

Model Config:

```
<cfg:groups>
            <cfg:group name="CMSExtensions.Model.Services" merger="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Configuration.Resources.DomainModelProcessor" merge="always">
                <cfg:domainmodel name="CMSExtensions.Model.Services">
                    <cfg:fileset>
                        <!-- <cfg:file type="script">/Scripts/Constants.js</cfg:file> -->
                    </cfg:fileset>

                    <cfg:services>                      
                        <cfg:service type="wcf">/Services/PublicationInfo.svc</cfg:service>
                    </cfg:services>
                </cfg:domainmodel>
            </cfg:group>
        </cfg:groups>
```

Web.config Entries:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="CMSExtensions.Model.Services.PublicationInfo" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.DeveloperBehavior">
        <endpoint name="PublicationInfo" address="" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.WebHttpBindingConfig" contract="CMSExtensions.Model.Services.PublicationInfo"/>
      </service>      
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: Can you share your web service code and the JavaScript of your command too? Without those it is pretty difficult to see what's going wrong here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - just added the code snippet.

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of that config? You can do it in any text editor and it will make it more readable to everyone here.

Answer (score 4):

Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.DeveloperBehavior is defined in the web.config file of the WebRoot directory. So most likely you are trying to run this in a different application (pool).

I suggest making sure that your model and editor are just virtual directories IIS and not applications.

Comment: It is setup as a Vdir and not a web application.

Comment: That's very strange. It should inherit it then. Have you tried just copying the behavior to your own web.config?

Answer (score 2):

If you correctly include your custom web service in your model's config file will generate a JavaScript proxy for calling your service. You can find the generated JavaScript code in the Default.aspx?mode=js file that you'll find in the debugging tools of your browser.

If the JavaScript proxy isn't in there, make sure that you've increased the Update number in your System.config. If you've done that and the proxy still doesn't show up, check the generated JavaScript and the event logs for error messages.